# PHP Functions Return Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, return

The [PHP array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) says that `Array assignment always involves value copying`.  Is this true when a function returns an array?

Specifically, I'd like to return copies of a private array so that modifications to the returned array made by the calling code don't affect the class's private array:

```
class Insecurity {

  private $everyonesPasswordsInPlainText = ["abcd"];

  public function showPassesToHacker() {
    return $this->everyonesPasswordsInPlainText;
  }

}

// shouldn't affect Insecurity->$everyonesPasswordsInPlaineText
$badSite = new Insecurity();
$passes = $badSite->showPassesToHacker();
array_push($passes, "1234");

$origPasses = $badSite->showPassesToHacker();

print_r($passes);     // ["abcd", "1234"]
print_r($origPasses); // ["abcd"]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `return $everyonesPasswordsInPlainText;` be `return $this->everyonesPasswordsInPlainText;` ?

Comment: So why not just try it? It would have cost you less time than writing this question.

Comment: You are right, as you have it the `$passes` variable will be a **copy** of the `Insecurity::$everyonesPasswordsInPlainText` property.  (However you do need to prepend it with `$this` as Manju pointed out.)  However, you have kind of answered your own question, as you said you don't want outside code to affect your **private** array.  Well, the point of private properties is that you can't directly modify them from outside your class.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys.  Thought it'd be useful to document the question here on SO since I couldn't find a specific answer in the docs.

Comment: @jtfairbank Everything is always passed by-value apart from objects and resources, unless you explicitly use references (not entirely true but the reality is far too complicated to get into in a comment and it's effectively true in practice). That said, the situation is somewhat more complex than that - if you check memory usage at each step you will see that you don't get a full copy, you only get a potential copy - a full copy is only performed when this "potential copy" is modified (this is called copy-on-write).